# How to compare one column value with multiple column value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a new column based on Multiple column value. for example,

df:

```
   Num   A   B   C    D
0   56  65  96  46  325
1   25  96  65  35   24
2   69  23  59  63   22
3   89  46  94  79  259
```

df_output:

```
   Num   A   B   C    D   E
0  56    65  96  46  325  65
1  25    96  65  35  24   24
2  69    23  59  63  22   69
3  89    46  94  79  259  94
```

I need to create a new column E based on the column value in Num,
suppose if the Num Column value is >=50 then i need the next highest number in E column
when compared to A,B,C,D else next lowest value.

EXAMPLE:
In row1 Num=56, when we compared to A,B,C,D the next highest number after 56 is 65.

Comment: Your input and output data isn't consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly this isn't pretty but gets the job done. If you need something scalable (ie for analyzing more or less columns, this should be further refined. Nonetheless, it answers your example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
                    {
                    'Num' : [56,25,69],
                    'A': [65,96,23],
                    'B': [96,65,59],
                    'C': [46,35,63],
                    'D': [325,24,22]
                    }
)

def next_num(num, a,b,c,d):
    test_num = num
    l = []
    if a > test_num:
        l.append(a)
    if b > test_num:
        l.append(b)
    if c > test_num:
        l.append(c)
    if d > test_num:
        l.append(d)
    l.sort()

    if len(l) == 0:
        return test_num
    else:
        return l[0]

df['E'] = df.apply(lambda x: next_num(x['Num'], x['A'], x['B'], x['C'], x['D']), axis=1)
```

Dataframe:

```
In [24]: df
Out[24]:
   Num   A   B   C    D
0   56  65  96  46  325
1   25  96  65  35   24
2   69  23  59  63   22
```

Result:

```
In [25]: df['E'] = df.apply(lambda x: next_num(x['Num'], x['A'], x['B'], x['C'], x['D']), axis=1)

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
   Num   A   B   C    D   E
0   56  65  96  46  325  65
1   25  96  65  35   24  35
2   69  23  59  63   22  69
```